# iOS AudioQueue input stops before all recorded data is flushed

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, audioqueueservices

I'm using an AudioQueue for iOS that is recording user audio data on a button press. When the user presses a button, it records. When he releases the button, it stops recording. However, the audio is cutting off prematurely. When the user presses the stop button and goes to listen to the audio, some of the audio on the end is missing. I've also tried calling the function with "false" to stop immediately and listening for the property callback and that doesn't fix it.

How can I salvage the last moments of recording?

```
- (void)stopInputAudioQueue:(BOOL)immediately
{
    recording = NO;

    OSStatus err;

    // Stop queue
    err = AudioQueueStop( inputQueue, immediately  ? true : false );
    if( err != noErr )
        MyNSLog( @"AudioQueueStop() error: %d", (int)err );

    if( immediately )
    {
        [self disposeInputQueue];
    }
}
void IsRunningProc(  void *inUserData, AudioQueueRef inAQ, AudioQueuePropertyID inID )
{
    UInt32 isRunning;
    UInt32 size = sizeof( isRunning );

    // We had an issue!
    OSStatus result = AudioQueueGetProperty( inAQ, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning, &isRunning, &size );
    if( result!=noErr )
    {
        MyNSLog( @"AudioQueueGetProperty() error: %d", result );
        return;
    }

    AudioQueue *audioQueue = (__bridge AudioQueue *)inUserData;

    if( isRunning )
    {
        MyNSLog( @"AudioQueue is running." );
        if( [[audioQueue delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(audioQueueStarted)] )
            [[audioQueue delegate] audioQueueStarted];
    }
    else
    {
        [audioQueue disposeInputQueue];

        MyNSLog( @"AudioQueue is NOT running." );
        if( [[audioQueue delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(audioQueueStopped)] )
            [[audioQueue delegate] audioQueueStopped];
    }
}

- (void)disposeInputQueue
{
    if( inputQueue==NULL )
        return;

    MyNSLog( @"Calling AudioQueueRemovePropertyListener()" );

    // Remove listener
    AudioQueueRemovePropertyListener( inputQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning, IsRunningProc, (__bridge void *)(self) );


    MyNSLog( @"Calling AudioQueueDispose()" );

    // Now get rid of the queue
    AudioQueueDispose( inputQueue, true );
    inputQueue = NULL;
}
```